# Don't let bots index ephemeral pages

Tags: feature-request, seo, robots

While googling for "[Intellij GWT HTTP ERROR: 500  No realm](https://www.google.com/search?q=intellij%20gwt%20HTTP%20ERROR%20500%20%20No%20realm) ", I got a few SO hits with obsolete URLs:

```
Newest 'gwt' Questions - Page 8 - Stack Overflow
stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt?page=8&sort=newest
Block all stackoverflow.com results
50 answers - 11 Nov
Is there way to tell IntelliJ IDEA which output folder to use for GWT .... “HTTP ERROR: 500 No realm” running GWT's “MobileWebApp” sample ...
```

At the time of indexing, this question probably was on page 8, but it's not there anymore. What do you think about disallowing these kind of urls (having *sort=newest* for example)?

Comment: In general, I dislike *all* such results, even if the links are okay.

Comment: I'm guessing that these pages produce a lot of Google mojo for Stack Exchange. Agree with you, but don't think they'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks to this question, now I see a lot more of these from that link: Unanswered 'robots' Questions - Meta Stack Exchange, Unanswered 'seo' Questions - Meta Stack Exchange, Highest Voted 'robots' Questions - Meta Stack Exchange, Newest 'gwt-hosted-mode' Questions - Stack Overflow, Newest 'gwt' Questions - Page 222 - Stack Overflow

Comment: @AndrewT. your comment makes it even worse ;-)